# Rewrite parameters in query string to be compatible to php array

Tags: php, nginx, lua

PHP accept array parameters in the query string using the `[ ]` format

> http://my.url/bar.php?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3&foo[]=4

I need to allow the format without square brackets

> http://my.url/bar.php?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3&foo=4

I don't want to change my application so I thought about rewrite the second URL to the first one. Is this possible in NGINX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is achievable with a quite simple **lua** script.

You could:

- loop [`get_uri_args()`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_uri_args)

  - accumulate multiple values for the same key in a new `key[]` variable
- put the new args in place using [`set_uri_args()`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_uri_args)

Something like the following (not tested, ajust to your real case):

```
// "foo=val1&bar=baz%foo=val2"
location = /test {
   content_by_lua_block {
     local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
     local qs = {}
     for key, val in pairs(args) do
         if type(val) == "table" then
             table.insert(qs, key.."[]" .. table.concat(val, key.."[]"))
         else
             table.insert(qs, val)
         end
     end
     // qs = { foo[] = {"val1", "val2"}, bar = "baz" }
     ngx.req.set_uri_args(qs)
   }
   // "foo[]=val1&foo[]=val2&bar=baz"
}
```

***Note**: this has to be extended if you whant to take into account "multidimensional" arrays too.*